# Merge Two Interfaces

Tags: typescript

Seeking confirmation or clarification

If I have two interfaces. What is the "proper" way to create a merge of those two interfaces?

```ts
IFoo {
  // some stuff
}


IBar {
  // some stuff
}


IFooBar extends IFoo, IBar {
 // Empty
}
```

It works but it feels weird, like I am doing it wrong with the empty IFooBar.

Am I doing this correctly?

*I also noticed that this also works:*

```ts
type IFooBar = IFoo & IBar;
```

I have an illogical aversion to using `type` yet, it is much cleaner.

Answer (score 297, accepted):

[This article](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/interface-vs-type-alias-in-typescript-2-7-2a8f1777af4c) explains the relation between interfaces and type aliases very well, [this part](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/interface-vs-type-alias-in-typescript-2-7-2a8f1777af4c#722b) is focused on small differences between them.

Both

```
interface IFooBar extends IFoo, IBar {}
```

and

```
type IFooBar = IFoo & IBar;
```

are common ways to do this and will behave identically in most cases. Since `type` takes less characters to type, it could be chosen for that reason.

The inconsistency that is caused by mixed `interface` and `type` shouldn't be a problem; they are just suitable features to achieve the goal. If `const BarClass = FooClass` does the job, `class BarClass extends FooClass {}` shouldn't be preferred just because its consistently uses `class` everywhere (this example is used for illustrative purposes, there's a considerable difference between these approaches).

Even though `interface` and `type` can behave similarly, there is a difference in case of merged interface (also covered in linked article). This will work:

```
interface FooBar extends IFoo, IBar {}
class FooBar { ... }
```

And this will cause type error:

```
type FooBar = IFoo & IBar;
class FooBar { ... }
```

Comment: Definitely agree, probably the most immediate thing that  initially stands out between intersections and interface extensions is how the types of properties, and especially methods, are merged.

Comment: The first approach now gives error while compiling, TS 3.4.3

Comment: @Musa Which one? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @EstusFlask I think I made a mistake, they both are still supported, my confusion resulted from below error.


`ERROR in src/app/pages/requests/details/details.types.ts(82,18): error TS2320: Interface 'IRequestDetailsForm' cannot simultaneously extend types 'IRequestContractPartial' and 'IAVRCSVendor'.
  Named property 'contractor_license_number' of types 'IRequestContractPartial' and 'IAVRCSVendor' are not identical.`

Comment: @Musa Yes, it seems that these two interfaces are incompatible.

Answer (score 17):

If you're wanting to **merge 2 interfaces which contain members more than 1 level deep**:

```
export interface TypeOne  {
  one: {
    two: {
      hello: string;
    }[]
  }
}

export type TypeTwo = {
  one: {
    two: {
      world: string;
    }[]
  }
} & TypeOne;

const x: TypeTwo;
x.one.two[0]. // autocomplete options are 'hello' / 'world'
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working fine, is there a way for this to be done with `interface` somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I think there it is ok, or not ok relating to what meaning of the merged interface. If `IFooBar` is a new entity from perspective of object-oriented design, then empty interface is all right. But if there is no such entity, but you want just merge some unrelated interfaces (for some hacky code) - then just use `IFoo & IBar` in variable type definition, or `type` for shortening this.

It's just my opinion as programmer, that came from object oriented languages like C++ and C#.