# Structural typing and Polymorphism - Adding super types

Tags: angular, typescript, design-patterns, polymorphism, structural-typing

Below is an example code(polymorphic) taken from [angular framework](https://github.com/angular/angular) using TypeScript syntax,

```
export abstract class AbstractControlDirective {
   ...
}
```

---

**`AbstractControlDirective` subtypes**

```
export abstract class NgControl extends AbstractControlDirective {
     ...
}
export abstract class ControlContainer extends AbstractControlDirective {
   ...
}
export declare abstract class ControlContainer extends AbstractControlDirective {
  ...
}
export declare abstract class NgControl extends AbstractControlDirective {
    ...
}
```

---

**`NgControl` subtypes**

```
export class NgModel extends NgControl implements OnChanges, OnDestroy {
   ...
}

export class FormControlDirective extends NgControl implements OnChanges {
    ....
}

export class FormControlName extends NgControl implements OnChanges, OnDestroy {
   ...
}

export declare class FormControlDirective extends NgControl implements OnChanges {
    ...
}

export declare class FormControlName extends NgControl implements OnChanges, OnDestroy {
   ...
}

export declare class NgModel extends NgControl implements OnChanges, OnDestroy {
   ...
}
```

In general, there are many situations, that came across new requirements, to add obvious looking super type in intermediate layers of class hierarchy, that injects breakage in subtypes, unless using some design pattern. Using design pattern can make the class hierarchy less error prone but breaks the hierarchy structure.

---

To avoid this problem, Can we maintain this hierarchy without using `extends` keyword? TypeScript being structural typed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class should inherit from a parent (`extends` keyword in ES6 classes) if one or more following conditions are satisfied:

- parent class has explicit constructor that should be inherited in child class, including class fields and constructor parameter properties (which are syntactic sugar for ES6 class constructor body).
- parent class has concrete prototype members (methods and getters/setters) that should present in child class
- instances of child class should be identifiable as parent class instances at runtime with `child instanceof Parent`
- parent class has decorators that affect anything of the above

Otherwise inheritance doesn't provide any benefits and results in excessive prototype chain; child class can just implement parent interface (`implements` keyword).

[`AbstractControlDirective`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.9/packages/forms/src/directives/abstract_control_directive.ts#L20) contains concrete members that should be inherited in child classes, so [`NgControl`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.9/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_control.ts#L27) extends it:

```
export abstract class NgControl extends AbstractControlDirective {...}
```

[`HttpXsrfTokenExtractor`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.9/packages/common/http/src/xsrf.ts#L26) contains only abstract members, so [`HttpXsrfCookieExtractor`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.9/packages/common/http/src/xsrf.ts#L39) doesn't need to extend it and just implements it as an interface:

```
export class HttpXsrfCookieExtractor implements HttpXsrfTokenExtractor {...}
```

Comment: For your point: *parent class has concrete members that should present in child class*. Did you come across a scenario, where you add a method in parentclass that needs for 4 child classes but not for 2 other child classes( as it does not make sense). It is easy to say that, class hierarchy was not well designed, as we got into this scenario. But, how would you react to this scenario?

Comment: Firstly, why would I care, if 2 or more child classes are getting affected? I want to target only those 4 child classes. For the category havinf those 2, I came across tens of classes in real  time that got affected after the code went in production.

Comment: From testing aspect, scope increases, for such changes

Comment: So, am trying to understand, how do we maintain type relationships, without using `extend` keyword. Can't the points mentioned in your first two bullet points be taken care using composition? And third point using structural typing?

Comment: If class hierarchy went wrong at some point, it should be refactored or left as, depending on how crucial or costly it is. it is. If base class is Human but it appears that child classes are John, Rick, Duck and Robot, base class likely should become Biped, and Human, Duck and Robot  should directly inherit from it. This problem likely doesn't have any consequences except design, because classes interfaces contain members that shouldn't be there, like duck.speak(). But I'm not sure how this applies to the question.

Comment: You can maintain type inheritance with either interface inheritance or union types (they are mostly interchangeable but there may be some differences, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49723584/3731501). It remains unclear why the subject is an issue for you. If you need inheritance, you need it (except cases [when you don't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)). An alternative to inheritance is to post same methods to classes that implement same interface, which is a no-no. You can't mimic bullet points with structural typing - this is what inheritance is for.

Comment: There are low-level alternatives to `extends` like Object.setPrototypeOf - ES6 classes are syntactic sugar, and this is what TS uses to transpile them to ES5. You need to have a good idea how JS inheritance works and how TS code translates to JS. It would be more substantial if you had real examples that trouble you - you've just moved from Angular classes to your own without showing them.