# Create interface based on properties of other interfaces

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I have two interfaces, `Workflow` and `WorkflowVersion`

*workflow.model.ts*

```
import { WorkflowVersion } from './workflow-version.model';

export interface Workflow{
    name: string;
    ID: number;
    workflowVersions: WorkflowVersion[];
}
```

*workflow-version.model.ts*

```
export interface WorkflowVersion{
    versionID: number;
    lastPublished: string;
    environmentID: number;
}
```

I'd like to create an interface that 'flattens' the two. This new interface, `WorkflowFlat`, should contain all non-object type properties of both interfaces. Currently I have this:

*workflow-flat.model.ts*

```
export interface WorkflowFlat {
    name: string;
    ID: number;
    versionID: number;
    lastPublished: string;
    environmentID: number;
}
```

The model above achieves this, but it feels repetitive. If I want to add a `description` property to `WorkflowVersion` down the road, I'd have to remember to also add it to `WorkflowFlat`. Is there any way to make the model automatically take all properties from the two interfaces and then create a new interface with the non-object ones?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge Two Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49723173/merge-two-interfaces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aaron Beall's answer is close (sorry I can't comment yet), but it doesn't properly remove all the keys that extends `object`, so they'll be required by the final type as `key: never` which is not wanted.

The following snippet achieves the objective by reusing a type-level helper from the awesome [tycho01/typical repo](https://github.com/tycho01/typical):

```
export type NonMatchingPropNames<T, X> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends X ? never : K }[keyof T];

export type NonMatchingProps<T, X> = Pick<T, NonMatchingPropNames<T, X>>;

type PrimitiveValuesOf<T> = NonMatchingProps<T, object>;

type A = PrimitiveValuesOf<Workflow & WorkflowVersion>;

const a: A = {
  name: '',
  ID: 0,
  versionID: 1,
  lastPublished: '',
  environmentID: 2
}; // OK
```

Comment: I missed that `never` still appeared, this answer is the right one!

Comment: I'm new to typescript and this is the first time I've heard about type operations... I have a lot of reading up to do!

Comment: to be honest, this is about as far as I would go in terms of type-level utilities: they are fascinating and compact ways to improve the type safety of a codebase, but it's hard to judge what behavior is "public API" of TS versus what is at risk to be breaking with the next release.