# how to loop through the union of two interface Props in React with Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native

From the structure below working with `React 16.9.0` and `Typescript ^16.9.20"`:

```
file A.ts:
export interface person{
  id: number || null,
  first_name: string,
  date_of_birth: string,
  some_unique_number: string,
}


file B.ts:
export interface member{
 group_name: string:
 first_name: string,
 pass_code: string,
 some_unique_number: string,
}


file C.tsx:
# import file A
# import file B

interface Props {
  result: Array<person | member>; 
}

let newResult: any[] = [];                       <=== I feel like `any[]` is wrong maybe

if (result) {
    newResult = results.map((result) => {
      return (
        <div className="something" key={item.some_unique_number}>
          {result.id}
          {result.first_name}
          {result.date_of_birth}
          {result.group_name}
          {result.pass_code}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
```

My current solution above is generating the error below:

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'person | member'.
  Property 'id' does not exist on type 'member'.  TS2339

    20 |         <div className="something" key={item.external_member_id}>
  > 21 |           {item.id}
```

Basically what i am trying to accomplish is loop through both interface and display the union of 
both A and B.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible Duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49723584/5283424 Both interface IFooBar extends IFoo, IBar {} and type IFooBar = IFoo & IBar;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge Two Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49723173/merge-two-interfaces)

Comment: @MichaelDimmitt mine is actually different as i have to use `Array<person | member>` not `&`. any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Lets simplify your code for better understanding. We create two different interfaces A and B and adding for each interface one item into the `results` variable.

```
interface A {
  name: string
  age: number
}

interface B {
  name: string
  country: string
}

results: Array<A | B> = [
 {name: "Mike", age: 30},
 {name: "John", country: "DE"}
]
```

Lets have a look into this two code pieces, which are trying to render the results items.

```
results.map((item) => 
  <div>{item.name}</div> // works as expected
)

results.map((item) => 
  <div>{item.name}-{item.age}</div> // you will get a typescript error
)
```

In the first `results.map` we are using only the property `name`. If you try to run this code it will work because of the property `name` is in both `interfaces` `A` and `B`. For the second `result.map` you will get a Typescript Error that the property `age` does not exist in interface B.
How can we solve this issue?

The solution is called **Type Guards**!
Type guards ensure that your item has the property or is of interface A or B.

```
results.map((item) => {
  return (
    <div>{result.name}</div> // both interfaces have this property
    <div>{"age" in result ? result.age : ""}</div> // ensure the item has the property age 
    <div>{"country" in result ? result.country : ""}</div> // ensure item has the property country
  )
})
```

You can also use functions to identify which interface is the item.
It makes the code more readable when your interfaces have a lot of different properties and you don't want to check each property by its own.

```
const isA = (item: A | B): item is A // here you tell Typescript that the function parameter item is of interface A in case this function returns true {
  return 'age' in A; // check properties which are unique - in this case the interface A has a property age which interface B does not have
}
```

And with this type guard function your code will look like

```
results.map((item) => {
  if (isA(item)){
    return (
       <div>{item.name}</div>
       <div>{item.age}</div>
    )
  }

  return (
     <div>{item.name}</div>
     <div>{item.country}</div>
  )
})
```

Now typescript knows that in the if block we are handling all items with the interface A and after this code block we are handling items with the interface B because we just have this two interfaces in `results`.

Switch the type of `newResults` from `any[]` to `ReactNode[]`.

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/interface-vs-type-alias-in-typescript-2-7-2a8f1777af4c

from the article -
"You can define same interface multiple times, and its definitions will merge into one:"

[image: Typescript merge example]

Not sure if this works but if we were being creative with your example:

```
// file A.ts
export interface person{
  id: number || null,
  first_name: string,
  date_of_birth: string,
  some_unique_number: string,
}


// file B.ts:
export interface member{
 group_name: string:
 first_name: string,
 pass_code: string,
 some_unique_number: string,
}

export interface peopleOrMember extends member
export interface peopleOrMember extends person
```

hope that works for you, 
If it still does not work maybe it is somewhere in that medium link.
I copied that link out of the other stackoverflow question that I mentioned.