# typescript, create type combine option value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In typescript.

I have a type `A`:

```
interface A {
    a1: string;
    a2: int;
}
```

And a `B`:

```
interface B {
    b1: number
}
```

And now I want a type:

```
interface AB {
    a1?: string;
    a2?: string;
    b1: string;
}
```

Which combine all `A` option value and `B`

How can I do this in typescript?

Comment: `type AB = A & B`

Comment: `type AB = Partial<A> & B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered previously here: [Merge Two Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49723173/merge-two-interfaces), the only difference is the usage of a Partial which [Constructs a type with all properties of Type set to optional. This utility will return a type that represents all subsets of a given type.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype):

You can either create a new interface:

```js
interface Ci extends Partial<A>, B {}
```

or create a type:

```js
type Ct = Partial<A> & B
```

Try the following on the typescript playground:

```js
interface A {
  a1: string
  a2: number
}

interface B {
  b1: number
}

interface Ci extends Partial<A>, B {}

type Ct = Partial<A> & B

const interfaceType: Ci = {a1: 'blah', a2: 1, b1: 2}

const typeType: Ct = {a1: 'blah', a2: 1, b1: 2}

const partialInterfaceType: Ci = {b1: 1}

const partialTypeType: Ct = {b1: 1}

console.log('interfaceType', interfaceType)
console.log('typeType', typeType)
console.log('partialInterfaceType', partialInterfaceType)
console.log('partialTypeType', partialTypeType)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgRgC5kBnMKUAcxzwCZiQBXAWwCNosBfLLUSWRCgBCmGqyLImbDt17ho8JMgDCwZBAAekEABMSyAApwoYYHAA2AHlQA+ADTIRGWWACeABxTKwyALyHjUwtrG2QAMkceBAB7EDJkPgVBABUPCGJVP0wCYgByVnM4AAtchzh6ZHwHcWJaWRi4nzdPVM8Mn38MHOR8wpKyiqrkGuQ6qNj490CzcwBJeQEkVvSVNU6R-HqJnymTGeXljLXMDa246PMIADpzaMoAClzExYhl0oSFxVe0gEosBpIF2utweuWa30873Byz+AKBNzuj12QTmnxSaXeyJm834Xxh-wm8JBSOmFgOGIcWLJaRhQA)